# Pass a TypeScript Type as a prop to a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to pass a TypeScript type as a prop to a React Component?

```
export type ActivitiesType = {
  RUN: "RUN";
  WALK: "REST";
  ROUNDS: "ROUNDS";
};

<MyComponent activity={ActivitiesType.RUN} />
```

Then in MyComponent:

```
const MyComponent = ({ activity }) => {
  if(activity === ActivitiesType.RUN) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible as types aren't there at runtime. Why not using a field `type` in activity? [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?q=166#example/discriminate-types) is more from the official doc

Comment: Why not use Enums?

Comment: You are looking for generics, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208569/using-generics-between-props-for-a-react-component maybe is a duplicate

Comment: Related: [How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818849). Your type is essentially an ambient enum. You need a real one that exists at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ritaj was right, Enums can do this:

```
enum ActivitiesType {
  RUN: "RUN";
  WALK: "REST";
  ROUNDS: "ROUNDS";
}

type Props = {
  type: ActivitiesType;
}
```